# R: control scale in ggplot2's legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following R code:

```
ggplot(data=curve,aes(x = expected, y=result/games)) + 
geom_point(aes(x=-expected, colour=games)) +
stat_function(fun=funx, geom="line", col="blue") + 
scale_colour_continuous(name="Number of games")
```

However in my legend I get values like 1e+05, 2e+05 .. 6e+05 etc.
My problem is that some values are very low (from 0-100) and some are very huge (up to 600000). I was planning to use "break", for specifying ranges from 0-10, 11-100, 1001-5000) etc. However when I put this into scale_colour_continuous only legend changes, but not colors on my graph.

UPDATE:

I used suggested solutions but I get error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(result, games) : / not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(result, games) : / not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(result, games) : / not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Without example data from `curve`, I can't help more.  If `curve` does not have too many rows, the output of `dput(curve)` would be most useful.  If there are a lot of rows, make some subset that has a a variety of values for `expected`, `result`, and `games` and give the `dput()` of that.  I seems like you overwrote the `games` variable with the discrete version. You need to make it a different variable since you use both `games` and the discrete version of `games`.

Comment: @Brian: dput(curve) done, i've updated the question. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to discretize the scale, it is easiest if you do change the variable (or create a new variable) and plot with that instead.  ggplot can't convert a continuous variable into a discrete one itself.

```
curve$games.d <- cut(curve$games, breaks=c(0,10,100,5000,Inf), 
  labels=c("0-10", "11-100", "101-5000", "5000+"), include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Then plot with `colour=games.d` and if you need to tweak the scale more (label, etc.) use `scale_colour_discrete`.

UPDATE

Thanks for the `dput` output.  It makes it clear where the error is now.

```
> str(curve)
'data.frame':   223 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ expected: int  -402 -400 -391 -390 -386 -385 -383 -380 -379 -375 ...
 $ result  : Factor w/ 194 levels "0","0,5","1",..: 3 3 3 30 2 3 2 3 3 2 ...
 $ games   : int  1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ colgame : Factor w/ 4 levels "0","100","5000",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Notice that `result` is a factor.  I presume you are using the notation where the decimal separator is a comma rather than a period.  These must be converted to numbers (see further note later for a way to avoid this in the first place)

```
curve$result <- as.numeric(gsub(",",".",as.character(curve$result)))
```

Now your graphing code would be: (I commented out the `stat_function` call since I don't have your function `funx`).

```
ggplot(data=curve,aes(x = expected, y=result/games)) + 
geom_point(aes(x=-expected, colour=colgame)) +
#stat_function(fun=funx, geom="line", col="blue") + 
scale_colour_discrete(name="Number of games")
```

[image: ggplot plot]

As to how to possibly avoid this in the first place, presuming that your read this in from a CSV file, look at `read.csv2` or the `dec` argument to the `read.table` family of functions to specify the decimal specifier for numbers.

Comment: I am so stupid. I have just changed it in excel in order to be able to sort by numbers and by accident I must have saved it :) thanks for spotting the error! Now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

If you put a reproducible example it would we easier to help. And I'm not sure to understand what you want. But some pointers to do what you want.

If you want to use breaks and to change the colours then you need to map colours to an aesthetic.

Lending from Brian Diggs example:

```
curve$games.d <- cut(curve$games, breaks=c(0,10,100,5000,Inf), 
  labels=c("0-10", "11-100", "101-5000", "5000+"), include.lowest=TRUE)

ggplot(data=curve,aes(x = expected, y=result/games, colour = games.d)) + 
geom_point(aes(x=-expected)) +
stat_function(fun=funx, geom="line", col="blue") + 
scale_colour_continuous(name="Number of games")
```

HTH

Comment: Having `colour=games.d` in the `ggplot` call and `colour=games` in the `geom_point` will cause problems since it is being mapped to a discrete variable in one case and a continuous one in the other.

Comment: I get 
Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(result, games) : / not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(result, games) : / not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(result, games) : / not meaningful for factors